# Preventing Excel VBA compile errors due to users having an older version of MS Office (MS Outlook) installed?

Tags: vba, excel

If I have a spreadsheet where I've referenced MS Outlook 14.0 Object Library from the VBA editor, and a user who only has MS Outlook 12.0 installed, then when that user opens the spreadsheet, they get a compile error on this line:

```
Range("export_date") = Date - 1
```

If they go into Tools, References, in the references list, there is this error:

```
MISSING: MS Outlook 14.0 Object Library
```

If they deselect that library, and instead select

> MS Outlook 12.0 Object Library

...the code then properly compiles and the spreadsheet works fine for them.

I don't really understand why it fails on the Date() function, as that is VBA function, not an Outlook function.  But even more important, is there a way to avoid this situation?  The only thing I can think of is to not set references, and just use variables of type Object and instantiate via CreateObject("Outlook.Application"), etc, but I hate to give up strong typing, etc.

Can anyone suggest a superior way to handle this issue of backwards compatibility with older versions of MS Office?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

tbone, what you refer to as **Strong Typing** is called "Early Binding".

*Unfortunately one of the drawbacks with Early Binding is that if the end user doesn't have the same version as yours then you will get those errors.*

If you ask me, I prefer Late Binding (where you don't create references and use CreateObject to create an instance)

An interesting read.

**Topic: Using early binding and late binding in Automation**

**Link**: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115

**My Suggestion**

Don't give up Early Binding if you like it because of intellisense. However before you distribute your application, change the code to Latebinding. There is not much of a difference in the way you code in Early Binding and Late Binding.

Here is an example

**Early Binding**

```
'~~> Set reference to Excel Object Library
Sub Sample()
    Dim oXLApp As Excel.Application
    Dim oXLBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oXLSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    '~~> Create a new instance of Excel
    Set oXLApp = New Excel.Application
    '~~> Add a new workbook
    Set oXLBook = oXLApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set oXLSheet = oXLBook.Worksheets(1)

    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End Sub
```

**Late Binding**

```
'~~> Doesn't require a reference to Excel Object Library
Sub Sample()
    Dim oXLApp As Object
    Dim oXLBook As Object
    Dim oXLSheet As Object

    '~~> Create a new instance of Excel
    Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    '~~> Add a new workbook
    Set oXLBook = oXLApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set oXLSheet = oXLBook.Worksheets(1)
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End Sub
```

HTH

Sid

Comment: Damn, your answer is what I was afraid was going to be the case.  "...before you distribute your application, change the code to Latebinding." - much easier said than done!!!! :)  Using an old type library would be preferable if a person did a lot of this, but for my case I'll just use Early Binding I guess.

Comment: @tbone: trust me. It is very easy to convert an Early Bind to a late bind :)

Comment: @tbone while you cou\ld try to add references to different outlook versions during runtime, I would go with Sid's advice on this. +1

Comment: > "It is very easy to convert an Early Bind to a late bind"  Agreed.  Not so easy to convert 20 of them, especially if you have the same problem, but with multiple different object types (Outlook, Word, etc).  Or is there a technique I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional compilation!
ex:

```
#if Updating then
     ...late binding
#Else
     ...early binding
#End If
```