# Programatically import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace in VBA project

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I'm trying to programatically import `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace into my vba project. I found [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb407651%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
that displays how to import it manually, but I'm giving this project that I've been working on to people that won't know how to import it. Can anybody please help?

Comment: Can you please clarify: if you have a VBA project (in Excel?), why do you need to import any namespace? Do you mean a "Reference" (= VBA term) to the Excel library? Namespace is a .NET term, usually not used in VBA context...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing Excel VBA compile errors due to users having an older version of MS Office (MS Outlook) installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491314/preventing-excel-vba-compile-errors-due-to-users-having-an-older-version-of-ms-o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from your question that your VBA code uses a reference to the Microsoft Excel 12.0 (or other version) library - and that your user gets an error as the reference cannot be found. In this case, you have two options:

- Instead of referring to the v12 library, refer to an older library, e.g. from Excel 2003. To do so, search the net for this library and install it - or simply "relink" your file in an Office 2003 installation before shipping
- Use late binding instead of early binding. In this case, you do not add a reference to the Excel library at all. Instead, you declare your objects as type `Object`(instead of `Excel.Workbook`, `Excel.Application`, etc.). To create a new object, instead of using `Set objExcelApp = New Excel.Application`, you must now use `CreateObject` (for new objects) or `GetObject` (for existing objects, e.g. an existing, running application): `Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`. Any later code will continue to work as usual (though it might be a tiny bit slower due to the late binding).

For further reading, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491314/preventing-excel-vba-compile-errors-due-to-users-having-an-older-version-of-ms-o).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've been traveling. But thanks so much Peter! I'm going to start late binding everything now :)

Comment: You're welcome! Only downside of late binding: you don't get the IntelliSense showing your the properties in the Editor. Therefore, I usually develop with early binding change to late binding before shipment...